# What tool chain should I use to build a vagrant base box automatically?

Tags: vagrant

Are there any tools that I can use to automatically build vagrant base boxes on a remote linux server. It'll be better if it is extendable and version control friendly.

Thanks. First question on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out veewee: https://github.com/jedi4ever/veewee

I'm not sure by "extendable" what you mean. veewee should do the job. it supports debian preseed file and other configurations that can be checked into version control.

Answer (score 2):

[Packer](http://www.packer.io) can create Vagrant boxes. It's from the same company that have created and maintain Vagrant.

http://www.packer.io/docs/post-processors/vagrant.html

Another valid option is [Veewee](https://github.com/jedi4ever/veewee), as pointed out in a previous answer.